# Load a LibSVM model file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, libsvm, svm

I have a couple of `libsvm` model files created by running svm train on a command line. I'm trying to load them into Matlab.
I've tried running the `libsvm2mat` program linked to [in a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787498/load-libsvms-model-file-in-matlab). When I try to run `svmpredict` in the Matlab terminal it gives me the error message:

```
"Error: can't read model: number of return field is not correct."
```

Any suggestions?

**Edit**: Furthermore, `libsvm2mat` gave me the warning messages `probA ignored!` and `probB ignored!` even though both of them are defined in the file.

Comment: How many outputs do you expect from `svmpredict`?

Comment: I want 3, but I get the same error message if I try to only get one output.

Comment: I got a similar error when I was trying to load a SVM model trained on Windows and use it on Mac. Re-training on Mac solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following MEX-function, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744997/97160):

#### libsvmloadmodel.c

```
#include "svm.h"
#include "mex.h"
#include "svm_model_matlab.h"

static void fake_answer(mxArray *plhs[])
{
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(0, 0, mxREAL);
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    struct svm_model *model;
    char *filename;
    const char *error_msg;
    int nr_feat;

    // check input
    if(nrhs != 2) {
        mexPrintf("Usage: model = libsvmloadmodel('filename', num_of_feature);\n");
        fake_answer(plhs);
        return;
    }
    if(!mxIsChar(prhs[0]) || mxGetM(prhs[0])!=1) {
        mexPrintf("filename should be given as string\n");
        fake_answer(plhs);
        return;
    }
    if(mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[1])!=1) {
        mexPrintf("number of features should be given as scalar\n");
        fake_answer(plhs);
        return;
    }

    // get filename and number of features
    filename = mxArrayToString(prhs[0]);
    nr_feat = (int) *(mxGetPr(prhs[1]));

    // load model from file
    model = svm_load_model(filename);
    if (model == NULL) {
        mexPrintf("Error occured while reading from file.\n");
        fake_answer(plhs);
        mxFree(filename);
        return;
    }

    // convert MATLAB struct to C struct
    error_msg = model_to_matlab_structure(plhs, nr_feat, model);
    if(error_msg) {
        mexPrintf("Error: can't convert libsvm model to matrix structure: %s\n", error_msg);
        fake_answer(plhs);
    }

    // destroy model
    svm_free_and_destroy_model(&model);
    mxFree(filename);

    return;
}
```

Example usage in MATLAB:

```
%# load some data, train a model, save it to file
[y,X] = libsvmread('./heart_scale');
model = libsvmtrain(y, X, '-c 1 -g 0.07 -b 1');
libsvmsavemodel(model, 'm.model');

%# load model from file, and use it to predict labels
m = libsvmloadmodel('m.model',size(X,2));
[yy, acc, prob_est] = libsvmpredict(y, X, m, '-b 1');
```

Note that `sv_indices` in the model is not persisted:

```
>> model
model = 
    Parameters: [5x1 double]
      nr_class: 2
       totalSV: 130
           rho: 0.42641
         Label: [2x1 double]
    sv_indices: [130x1 double]
         ProbA: -1.7801
         ProbB: -0.056797
           nSV: [2x1 double]
       sv_coef: [130x1 double]
           SVs: [130x13 double]
>> m
m = 
    Parameters: [5x1 double]
      nr_class: 2
       totalSV: 130
           rho: 0.42641
         Label: [2x1 double]
    sv_indices: []
         ProbA: -1.7801
         ProbB: -0.056797
           nSV: [2x1 double]
       sv_coef: [130x1 double]
           SVs: [130x13 double]
```

The saved model looks like:

#### m.model

```
svm_type c_svc
kernel_type rbf
gamma 0.07
nr_class 2
total_sv 130
rho 0.426412
label 1 -1
probA -1.7801
probB -0.0567966
nr_sv 63 67
SV
1 1:0.166667 2:1 3:-0.333333 4:-0.433962 5:-0.383562 6:-1 7:-1 8:0.0687023 9:-1 10:-0.903226 11:-1 12:-1 13:1 
0.6646947579781318 1:0.125 2:1 3:0.333333 4:-0.320755 5:-0.406393 6:1 7:1 8:0.0839695 9:1 10:-0.806452 12:-0.333333 13:0.5
```